# Django Custom Authentication Backend does not work

Tags: django, django-authentication

I've made a user model with `USERNAME_FIELD` defined as `phone_number`. So login form requires `phone_number` and `password`. I want users to be able to also login through their emails. So I created an authentication backend class. Users can login with their phone numbers but they canbot do so with their emails and will receive the 'Username and/or password is wrong' message.

authentication.py:

```py
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model


class CustomAuthBackend:
    def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None):
        try:
            user = get_user_model().objects.get(email=username)
            if password:
                if user.check_password(password):
                    return user
            return None
        except:
            return None

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            user = get_user_model().objects.get(pk=user_id)
            return user
        except:
            return None
```

forms.py:

```py
class UserLoginForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(label="Phone Number / Email")
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(), label="Password")
```

views.py:

```py
class UserLogin(View):
    form_class = UserLoginForm
    template_name = "accounts/login.html"

    def get(self, request):
        return render(request, self.template_name, {"form": self.form_class})

    def post(self, request):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            user = authenticate(
                request, username=cd["username"], password=cd["password"]
            )
            if user:
                login(request, user)
                messages.success(request, "Logged in successfully.", "success")
                return redirect("home:home")
            else:
                messages.error(request, "Username and/or password is wrong.", "danger")
                return render(request, self.template_name, {"form": form})
        messages.error(request, "Login failed", "danger")
        return render(request, self.template_name, {"form": form})
```

settings.py:

```py
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    "django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend",
    "accounts.authentication.CustomAuthBackend",
]
```

Comment: Do you mean it is working when users login phone numbers but not working with emails?

Comment: @Sunderam Dubey yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have already included the custom backend in `AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS` setting in `settings.py` file.

You can make a condition check that whether it is a phone no. or email using `regex` so:

```py
import re
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model


class CustomAuthBackend:
    def authenticate(self, request, username=None, password=None):
        UserModel = get_user_model()

        # Check whether username is an email address or phone number
        if re.match(r'^\+?\d{10,14}$', username):
            try:
                user = UserModel.objects.get(phone_number=username)
                if user.check_password(password):
                    return user
            except UserModel.DoesNotExist:
                return None
        else:
            try:
                user = UserModel.objects.get(email=username)
                if user.check_password(password):
                    return user
            except UserModel.DoesNotExist:
                return None

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            return get_user_model().objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except get_user_model().DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

Answer (score 1):

I had forgotten to include `request` as a parameter in `authenticate` method. :)
Correct version:

```py
def authenticate(self, request, username=None, password=None):
    # ...
```